# UpdatePanel not updating child div

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to validate that a username has not already been taken when the textbox value changes.  In the server-side callback, I add a class, either `has-success` if it's not taken or `has-error` if it has to an ancestor div.  Both of those are contained in an UpdatePanel.

However, despite the callback code running fine, the div's classes are never updated client-side.

#### Markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="divLoginFormGroup" runat="server" class="form-group has-feedback">
            ...
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbLogin" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="username" OnTextChanged="tbLogin_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" required />
            ...
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

#### Server-side

```
private void AddClass(HtmlGenericControl control, string className)
{
    control.Attributes["class"] += " " + className;
}

private void RemoveClasses(HtmlGenericControl control, params string[] classNames)
{
    foreach (string c in classNames)
    {
        control.Attributes["class"] = control.Attributes["class"].Replace(c, string.Empty);
    }
}

protected void tbLogin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = new LoginData().GetLoginByID(tbLogin.Text))
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            RemoveClasses(divLoginFormGroup, "has-success");
            AddClass(divLoginFormGroup, "has-error");
        }
        else
        {
            RemoveClasses(divLoginFormGroup, "has-error");
            AddClass(divLoginFormGroup, "has-success");
        }
    }
}

// Added per @sh1rts's answer, but I still have the same problem
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(tbLogin.UniqueID);
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

What am I missing here?

If it helps, the first OnTextChange goes through fine, but the second one always causes:

> Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem by calling RegisterForEventValidation - note that you can only do this in the page's Render method: -

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(tbLogin.UniqueID);
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and I get the same error.  It also didn't help updating the div.